# How do you read URLs from a .txt file to perform requests.get and save the responses to a file?

Tags: python, database, file, get, python-requests

I am able to save the response of a single URL but I have a list of URLs in a .txt file and would like to print the all the responses. How can I read the URLs from the .txt file and save the responses in python?

This is what I currently have. Thanks!

```
import requests

data = requests.get('www.url.com')

with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data.text)
```

Comment: Do you want to save all responses to the same file? or different files?

Comment: Same file please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you first want to read the urls from a file 'infile.txt', then iteratively send the requests and write the data to an outfile 'outfile.txt'.

```
with open('infile.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

datalist=[]
for url in urls:
    data = requests.get(url)
    datalist.append(data.text)

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in datalist:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to help me understand. Have a great day!